# Сделать хвост для змейки

Tags: c++

Всем привет! Я самостоятельно учу с++ и решил написать змейку. Для роста её хвоста при съедении еды я хотел использовать массив, хранящий положение головы в предыдущие ходы и выводить его циклом. Но у меня возникли проблемы. При первом съедении все работает нормально, а потом хвост не растет. Я попробовал сделать это без цикла.

Вся игра работает одним while. После всех рисовок происходит такой код:

```
prepos_x2 = prepos_x;
prepos_y2 = prepos_y;
prepos_x = zmeyka.x;
prepos_y = zmeyka.y;

и тут игра захватывает клавишу
```

Но он не сработал. Я проверил через cout и значение переменных prepos_x2 и prepos_y2 всегда равно prepos_x и prepos_y. Почему так происходит?

Upd:
По идее должно работать так:
Поле выполнено массивом pole[20][20]
Голова спавнится в месте[10][10] и затем перемешается с помощью нажатия нa стрелки
Хвост работает так

```
 If (golova.x = eda.x && golova.y = eda.y){
 dlina_hovsta = dlina_hvosta + 1;
 }

Затем 
for(i = 0; i < dlina_hvosta; i++) {
pole[hvost[i].x][hvost[i].y] = "1";
}

//Тут отрисовывается поле со всеми состовляющими

for(i =200; i>0; i--){
hvost[i].x = hvost[i - 1].x;
hvost[i].y = hvost[i- 1].y;
}
hvost[0].x = golova.x;
hvost[0].y = golova.y;
```

Comment: сложновато из представленного фрагмента кода дать, совет) можно больше данных?

Comment: Я добавил информации, но не знаю насколько она полезна... Я бы скинул весь срр, но уже компьютер выключил, да и вы бы все равно сломали там глаза.

Answer (score 1):

В условии у Вас вместо оператора сравнения "==" стоит оператор присваивания "=". Должно быть так

```
if (golova.x == eda.x && golova.y == eda.y){
    dlina_hovsta = dlina_hvosta + 1;
}
```